# Are the Theme frame works or Theme builders slow downs the performance?

Tags: themes, buddypress, performance

I depend on theme builders like Suffusion for my Multi-Site Installation. Some WP users say the theme frameworks slow downs the performance and load speed. Is that really affects the performance?

A follow up question... is there any chance for performance problem if I enable BuddyPress on same Installation

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The performance and load speed may be slowed down because of badly coded frameworks, or even well coded frameworks but way too overloaded. so it really depends on what framework or theme builder you are using and each one to its own case.

As for enabling BuddyPress, first you will need a theme that is made for BuddyPress and as far as i can tell Suffusion is not BuddyPress ready (I could be wrong here). And as for performance problem once again that is theme/theme framework depended.

Comment: Would you mind starting your paragraphs with an uppercase letter, i've been holding back saying anything, but it's chipping away at my inner grammar nazism.. Please.. :)

Comment: Sorry about that, i have to stop using my cell to for answers. Also feel free to correct me at anytime.

Comment: No problem, it's just a personal thing.. it's honestly not your fault, i'm just a picky reader, thanks for adding capitalization. :)

Comment: +1 to Bainternet. Asking if a framework will slow down performance is too generic. It depends on how much stuff the framework adds on. Each element that must load (scripts, stylesheets, images, etc) affects performance somewhat. BP on top of that is more to load. So it depends on the sum total of what all is loading, and how well it's coded.